# Chrome dev tools network preview not working when reload immediately

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I fetch something and reload page immediately, the network preview will load failed.
If I set timeout as 1000ms, sometimes succeeds sometimes fails;
and if I set timeout to 3000ms, it'll always work.

**I guess the error is interrupted by refresh page while reading data.**
So, **can I catch the "signal"... uh, I mean the "preview was loaded signal".**

I was already enable "Preserve log".

#### Contrast

[image]

#### Code

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin","<button>SEND</button>");

document.querySelector("button").onclick = () =>{
    fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://stackoverflow.com/").then(
    r => r.text()
  ).then(
    r => {
        console.log(r.split("\n")[0]);
      location.reload();  // Failed
      // setTimeout(()=>{location.reload();}, 3000);  // Success
    }
  )
}
```

#### Sample

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6rpzLt4/1/)

---

#### Environments

- Chrome: Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)